# Mac UI locked up. Are there any ways to unfreeze it short of cycling the power?

Tags: macos, freeze

My Mac's UI has locked up.

Is there any way to unfreeze the system short of cycling the power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have SSH enabled on it, you might be able to ssh in from another computer and at least give it a graceful restart with, e.g., `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: success! I was able to get in over ssh and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly has occurred. With Mac OS X would be unusual to see the entire system frozen. Much more likely a crashed app.

Have you tried a 'Force Quit' via command-option-escape?

Comment: UI is locked up, including keyboard command-option-escape no joy :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'd like more to find the reason for lock-ups and not just workarounds for symptoms.

UI freezing sounds very much like overheating video chips --- a common problem with many Macs, especially now during the summer in northern hemisphere.

I suggest you use e.g. [smcFanControl2](http://www.eidac.de/?cat=40) and tweak up the minimum fan speeds to keep your Mac running cooler.